# Integrate all Angular2 and Hapi routes

Tags: node.js, angular, get, routes, hapi.js

**Situation**

I'm developing a web application that uses Hapi server for REST calls and multi-page Angular2 website client-side.

Hapi serves all Angular2 files to the client with:

```
let serverDirPath = path.resolve(__dirname);
server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/{param*}",
    config: {
        auth: false,
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: path.join(serverDirPath, "../client"),
                index: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Calling the server root successfully returns "index.html", and after that the Angular2 website works perfectly! All calls to Hapi-defined routes also works fine.

**Issue**

However, if I execute a GET to any Angular2-defined route (for example to reach page "/users"), Hapi can't find the route and returns error 404. This is probably because the route is not defined on Hapi server. Please note that the "/users" route works perfectly if I navigate to there from the "index.html" page!

**Question**

How can I reach "/user" page with a direct GET call? If possible, I want to redirect all calls to Hapi routes to corresponding Angular2 routes (if they exist).

Thank you in advance!

**Edit: SOLUTION**

I solved it! In the app.module.ts, in the providers declaration, I added this:

```
    {
        // Strategy to serve pages with /#/{path}. It's required to resolve Angular2 routes when using hapi.
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
```

All Angular2 urls must be preceded by /#/ (e.g. localhost/#/home), which works great for me.

Comment: Hi, this is saved my skin. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have made the custom route handler, something like this

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{files*}',
    handler: function(req, reply, next) {
        var reg = /(\.js)|(\.css)|(\.png)|(\.jpg)|(\.jpeg)|(\.eot)|(\.woff)|(\.ttf)|(\.eot)|(\.svg)/;
        if(req.params.files && reg.test(req.params.files)) {
            reply.file(req.params.files);
        }
        else{
            reply.file('index.html');
        }

    }

});
```

also added this to connection config

```
server.connection({
...
routes: {
    files: {
        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, './public')
    }
  }
});
```

Haven't found any smartest way to handle this