# How to integrate AngularSPA and Hapi in 2020?

Tags: angular, heroku, hapi.js

I studied a bunch of articles and read tons of documentations without much result.
I have a Angular SPA app that uses routing, when in localhost my application works but after deploying it to Heroku, these routings will try some GET request and HAPI will answer with error 404.
The app endpoints of the REST services are ok and the Angular application is running well.
Angular routing links I have

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" href="/">Trades</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" href="/stocks_list">Stocks</a>
</nav>
```

I tried some tricks I found here but had no success on compilation the code with errors like follows.

```
    this.server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, h) => {
            const response = request.response;
        
            if (request.response && 'isBoom' in request.response 
            && request.response.message !== 'Invalid request payload input') {
              return h.continue;
            }
        
            if (response.output.statusCode === 404) {
              return h.file('index.html');
            }
          });
```

This code won't compile in the latest version of Hapi

```
      [ERROR] 23:56:28 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
    src/app.ts:77:26 - error TS2339: Property 'output' does not exist on type 'Boom<any> | ResponseObject'.
      Property 'output' does not exist on type 'ResponseObject'.
    
    77             if (response.output.statusCode === 404) {
                                ~~~~~~
    src/app.ts:78:24 - error TS2339: Property 'file' does not exist on type 'ResponseToolkit'.
    
    78               return h.file('index.html');
```

This is my app.ts, the only part that doesnt compile is the onPreResponse

```
import { Boom } from '@hapi/boom';
import * as Hapi from '@hapi/hapi'
import { plugins } from './plugins'

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const Path = require('path');
const Inert = require('@hapi/inert');

export class App {
  
  server: Hapi.Server;

  constructor (private host: string){
      console.log(`Trying to connect at ${host} port ${PORT}`)
      this.server = new Hapi.Server({
          host: host,
          port: PORT,
          routes: {
            files: {
                relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'frontend')
            },
            validate: {
                failAction: (request, h, err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    throw err;
                }
            },
            cors: {
                origin: [
                    'http://0.0.0.0',
                    'http://127.0.0.1',
                    'http://localhost:4200',
                    'stocks-price.herokuapp.com'
                ], // an array of origins or 'ignore'          
                additionalHeaders: [
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method',
                    'Allow-Origin',
                    'Origin',
                    'access-control-allow-origin',
                    'access-control-request-method',
                    'allow-origin',
                    'origin',
                ]
            }
        }
    });
  }

  start = async () => {
      try {
          await this.server.register(Inert)
          await this.server.register(plugins)

          this.server.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/{param*}',
            handler: {
              directory: {
                path: '.',
                redirectToSlash: true,
                lookupCompressed: true,
                index: true,
              },
            },
          });
        

          this.server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, h) => {
            const response = request.response;
        
            if (request.response && 'isBoom' in request.response 
            && request.response.message !== 'Invalid request payload input') {
              return h.continue;
            }
        
            if (response.output.statusCode === 404) {
              return h.file('index.html');
            }
          });

          await this.init();
          
          
          this.server.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/{param*}',
            handler: {
                directory: {
                    path: [Path.join(__dirname, 'frontend')],
                    listing: false,
                    index: ['index.html']
                }
            }
          })
                  
          await this.server.start()

      } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
          process.exit(1);
      }
  }

  init () {
      console.log('success on port: ' + this.server.info.port);
  }

}
```

Any help I'll be very glad, JS development is a nightmare these days specially when libraries changes and old samples won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to use the workaround of using hashes on the routing, that did the trick.

[Integrate all Angular2 and Hapi routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747229/integrate-all-angular2-and-hapi-routes)

Refer to this question and you'll find the answer. Its pretty easier than trying to hack Hapi.